# How to specify where to search for OnClick method, when onClick event occurs on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

1. I have created a Project in Android  Studio with ***default activity*** as *Navigation Drawer activity*
2. Then created two new fragment named **Myfragment1 and Myfragment2.**
3. Then implemented methods to call *appropriate fragments based on which option is selected from the navigation drawer*, I load those fragment using LayoutInflater inflate method, The code for same has been placed in method onCreateView of the MainActivity class.
4. When *Myfragment1* fragment gets loaded, if i click on add button which is on *Myfragment1* then it gives the error **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method".**
5. I have created the listener for the button in **onCreateView** of Myfragment1.java file
6. I have specified that it should search for o*nClick method in DatabaseActivity Class* but it is still giving the error

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

       private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
       private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment1, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment2, container, false);
                break;
            default:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment1, container, false);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**Myfragment1.java**

```
public class Myfragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfragment1, container, false);
    Button add = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view ;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_add:
            DatabaseActivity d= new DatabaseActivity();
            d.newProduct(v);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

**DatabaseActivity class**

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    EditText productBox;
    EditText quantityBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        productBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.productBox);
        quantityBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityBox);
    }

    public void newProduct (View view) {
        MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityBox.getText().toString());
        Product product = new Product(productBox.getText().toString(), quantity);
        dbHandler.addProduct(product);
        productBox.setText("");
        quantityBox.setText("");
    }
}
```

**Myfragment1.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.test.masterflow1.Myfragment1">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/delete_string"
    android:id="@+id/button_remove"
    android:onClick="removeProduct"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/find_string"
    android:id="@+id/button_find"
    android:onClick="lookupProduct"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_string"
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:onClick="newProduct"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="263dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/productBox"

    android:layout_below="@+id/productID_Box"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/productID_Box"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:id="@+id/quantityBox"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/productID_Box"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/quantityBox"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
```

**logcat**

```
22733-22733/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method newProduct(View) in the activity class com.test.masterflow1.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintButton with id 'button_add'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3791)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: newProduct [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3784)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
        at android.widget.Button.performClick(Button.java:139)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18395)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify the method you want it to call here:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_string"
    android:id="@+id/button_add"
    android:onClick="newProduct" <-- this is what it's trying to call
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

Notice, the error message isn't that it can't find the `onClick` method, but rather it can't find the `newProduct` method on the `Activity`:

> Could not find a method newProduct(View) in the activity class com.test.masterflow1.MainActivity

You'll need to remove the `onClick` property from the XML and set an `onClickListener` programmatically either in your fragment or your activity.

Comment: Can you provide me some reference to do so as i am a beginner an  learning by reading various tutorials. Dont know how to accomplish this

Comment: May be this will help http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/

Comment: @adityaNaik I have tried it in the same way as said there by overriding onclick method but its not working

Answer (score 0):

newProduct() on pressing Add button is getting called now. Did a lot of corrections, so don't really know where was the bug. Follow the code closely, and I think you'll figure it out yourself.

**myfragment1.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.masterflow1.Myfragment1">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_remove" <!--Use "@+id/..." for setting IDs -->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:onClick="removeProduct"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_find"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_remove" <!--And "@id/..." for referring them-->
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        android:onClick="lookupProduct"
        android:text="Find" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_find"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:onClick="newProduct"
        android:text="Add" />

<!-- your other widgets-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Myfragment1.java**

Follow proper Java naming convention. Refer [Google's Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

```
public class Myfragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment1, container, false);
    Button add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_add:
            DatabaseActivity d = new DatabaseActivity();
            d.newProduct(v);
            break;
    }
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Removed the navigation drawer code for simplicity

        private CharSequence mTitle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Do this for adding the fragment programatically. There's also .replace() when you want to replace the added fragment with another fragment.
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout_activity_main, new Myfragment1()).commit();
  //There's no onCreateView() lifecycle method in Activities. It belongs in Fragments. Move the code from your onCreateView() appropriately. 

   }}
```

My **activity_main.xml** was like this.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framelayout_activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**DatabaseActivity.java**

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText productBox;
EditText quantityBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    productBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.productBox);
    quantityBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quantityBox);
}

public void newProduct(View view) {
    Log.i("DatabaseActivity", "newProduct() Called");
    // do the DbHandler stuff here.

}}
```

Consider going through [Udacity's Android courses](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android). They are perfect for beginners.

**----EDIT----**

I think the bug might have been in your MainActivity#onCreateView() .  Try moving that switch block to Myfragment1#onCreateView(). Fragment's counterpart of Activity's onCreate() is onCreateView() . Read through the lifecycles of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).